# How can I do this with variables in php?

Tags: php

```
$name = "Shaab";
$age = 12;
echo $name."is".$age."years old";
```

It's output is

**Shaab is 12years old**

But i don't want to display it as above. I want to store this to another variable. Like

*result= Shaab is 12years old*

How can I do this?

Comment: Do please try to find some basic tutorials on php / google before asking questions here on Stack overflow, this is a very simple thing.

Comment: For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then, if you are sure your question fits the SO rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a good, well formed and on-topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question already have the answer.

```
$result =  $name."is".$age."years old";

echo $result;
```